# Dynamic Meta Tags via URL Variables

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags

If you're able to help with this problem, I'd appreciate it as I'm out of my depth.

I have a bunch of meta tags in a HTML header that need to map their content to variables in the URL. For example, if we have this URL:

`http://example.com?bofn=Dave&boln=Nate&boem=Pat&botn=Taylor&bstn=Chris&lstn=Rami`

We would want the meta tags in the header to read as this:

```
<meta name="bofn" content="Dave">
<meta name="boln" content="Nate">
<meta name="boem" content="Pat">
<meta name="botn" content="Taylor">
<meta name="bstn" content="Chris">
<meta name="lstn" content="Rami">
```

From what I've found online this would probably use javascript to function (URLSearchParams and/or location.search?) but I've no clue how to make it happen.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? Meta tags are normally read by robots/spiders that don't execute JavaScript, so creating them with JavaScript would be pointless.

Comment: I'm working with third-party software that uses meta tags in this way. I know it's not normal, but I don't have an alternative choice unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue with Pavel's help by replacing the URL with `window.location.href`:

```
<script>
var str = window.location.href;

// split('?')[1] takes all after '?' (removes http://example.com)
// split('&') creates array ('bofn=Dave', 'boln=Nate', ...)
var parts = str.split('?')[1].split('&');

// go through all variables
for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    // create new HTML element
    var el = document.createElement('meta');
   
    // split key, value
    var keyval = parts[i].split('=');

    // set name and content attributes, fill values in
    el.name = keyval[0];
    el.content = keyval[1];
    
    // append meta elements to head
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(el);
}
</script>
```

Comment: at least, you can upvote pavel's answer to as he make a great contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Split URL string into variables and its values, than go through them and create for each one new meta element.

```js
var str = 'http:example.com?bofn=Dave&boln=Nate&boem=Pat&botn=Taylor&bstn=Chris&lstn=Rami';

// split('?')[1] takes all after '?' (removes http://example.com)
// split('&') creates array ('bofn=Dave', 'boln=Nate', ...)
var parts = str.split('?')[1].split('&');

// go through all variables
for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    // create new HTML element
    var el = document.createElement('meta');
   
    // split key, value
    var keyval = parts[i].split('=');

    // set name and content attributes, fill values in
    el.name = keyval[0];
    el.content = keyval[1];
    
    // append meta elements to head
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: I tested it out on a [w3 space](https://shamrockform.w3spaces.com/index.html?bypass-cache=18235398&bofn=Dave&boln=Nate&boem=Pat&botn=Taylor&bstn=Chris&lstn=Rami) but no luck. I tried putting script in the body and header, keeping and removing the meta tags, and replacing the initial var with this:
`var url = new URL('https://shamrockform.w3spaces.com/index.html?bypass-cache=18070630&botn=Ringo');
var str = new URLSearchParams(url.search);`

Comment: I was able to fix part of the problem, but can only get the code to see the URL put in that first variable string, not the actual URL.

Comment: @ShamrockJedd current URL is in `window.location`.